# Get info on a particular Table "td" element

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a 10 X 8  table.

every row has 8  columns  ie..,  8 td elements. Each td in the row has a different class. Is it possible to get the  info of  1st **td** element in the row, when i click on any of the other td's in the row.

Basically i am creating a jquery onclick event on the  column 2 to column 8 of each row. When i click on any of this column(**td**) it should get the info ie.., either id or class or name attribute of the column 1.  I needs this one to send it on the server side code.

--
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From the clicked element, you navigate up to the row via [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), and then you can find the `td` with the relevant class with [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) or [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children) (probably `children` in case you have nested tables):

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var cell = $(e.target).closest('tr').children('td.foo');
    // ...
}
```

Or if you *always* want the *first* `td`:

```
var cell = $(e.target).closest('tr').children('td').first();
```

That handler will work if it's assigned to any `td` in the table, to the `tr`, or indeed to the `tbody` or `table` as a whole.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/usegih/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/usegih/1/edit)

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Put the handler on the tbody
  $("#target").click(clickHandler);

  function clickHandler(e) {
    var td = $(e.target).closest('tr').children('td').first();
    display("The text of the first <code>td</code> in that row is: " + td.text());
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="target">
  <tr>
    <td class="one">This is one in row 0</td>
    <td class="two">This is two in row 0</td>
    <td class="three">This is three in row 0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">This is one in row 1</td>
    <td class="two">This is two in row 1</td>
    <td class="three">This is three in row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">This is one in row 2</td>
    <td class="two">This is two in row 2</td>
    <td class="three">This is three in row 2</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, its working.  Btw one small query, is in the click event, can i append a hidden input with name="name of the first td: and value="value of the first td".  I tried that using - $("#tv-shows-feeds-form").append('<input name="'+cell.attr("name")+'" type="hidden" value="' 
                                            + cell.val() + '/>'); but its not working.

Comment: @SangramAnand: [`td` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-td-element.html#the-td-element) don't have either a `name` attribute or a `value`, which is why that isn't working (both `cell.attr("name")` and `cell.val()` probably come back `""`). You can append a field as you indicated, but I don't know what part of the cell you want for the name and value. (Perhaps by "value" you mean the text of the cell? That would be `cell.text()`. But I have no idea what you mean by the name.) In any case, that would be a different question. *This* question is answered, I believe. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could that like:

```
$('td.column2-8').click(function()
{
var firstTdData = $(this).parent().children('td:first').html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').click( function(){
    var $elem = $(this).parent('tr').children('td:first');
    var elem_id = $elem.prop('id'); // or $elem.attr('id');
    .... // for class, name, etc.
});
```